# PCA followed by k-means cluster analysis in R - understanding cluster means

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca

I'm doing a vegetation structure analysis for cocoa farms, using 13 variables, such as shade density, shade area, shade species richness etc. I want to group cocoa farms based on their vegetation structure and understand what the characteristics of each cluster is (method taken from Deheuvels et al., 2012).

I've done the pca and k-means but how do I understand what values of each variable the k-means centers correspond to as they are PC scores.

I performed a pca on my data which came out with 5 PCI's that explain 85% and above of the variation.

Using the scores of the 5 PCI's I performed a k-means cluster (k=5).

```
vd.pca <- princomp(vd, cor=TRUE, score=TRUE) # pca
summary(vd.pca)
veg <- cbind(vd.pca$scores[,1:5]) # extract 5 PC's

kcluster3 <- kmeans(veg, centers = 5) # k means cluster (k=5)
kcluster3$cluster #look at cluster
kcluster3$centers # look at centers

#k means centers 
#        Comp.1     Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4     Comp.5
# 1  0.28120797  1.0709242  1.2196432 -0.8616884 -1.1633793
# 2 -6.42093311 -1.2446623  0.8670286  0.3777479  0.2018202
# 3  2.04816824 -2.2148570  0.7875784 -0.1408710  0.1947974
# 4  0.31077215  0.9711477 -0.1162732  0.5096207  0.6571650
# 5  0.04296899 -0.6300695 -1.7649951 -0.2375636 -0.4360082
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the cluster labels, you can trivially *recompute* the **cluster centers in the original features**. (I guess you'll know how to compute means).

This will supposedly be more interpretable *except* for which feature differences are "larger" than others because of scaling.

Note that PCA *can* harm interpretability a lot because it changes scaing of variables.

Comment: I’m not sure how to compute means. Is there a way to control the changes in scaling?

Comment: Where is the scaling problem with the mean? It's computed one variable at a time.